# Set the text of a Textview from a returned String array

Tags: java, android, return

```
public String[] getpathsFromJSON (String JSONStringparam) throws JSONException{

    JSONObject JSONString = new JSONObject(JSONStringparam);

    JSONArray seriearray = JSONString.getJSONArray("results");
    String [] result = new String [seriearray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i<seriearray.length();i++){
        JSONObject serie = seriearray.getJSONObject(i);
        String serienaam = serie.getString("name");
        result[i] = serienaam;
    }
    return result;
}
```

i want to use one of the results in the return to display in a textview.
what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use just one result?

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewResourceId); 

view.setText(result[some_int_in_your_array]);
```

Since you're programming for Android I'm assuming you're using Android Studio so you can create the text view in the GUI interface for the XML and use findViewById.

If you want to display them all:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutViewEx);

for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());           
        textView.setText(result[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String>` in a `ListView` would be better here

Comment: @GerMex thank you very much! exactly where i was looking for. and yes i use android studio's.

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean wen i want to display them all ! then i better should use the listview + adapter?

Comment: @rickkorsten Correct. ListViews are optimized better than LinearLayouts for scrolling lists of data.

Comment: @cricket_007 how do i use the result outside the method or in another method?

Comment: @rickkorsten I don't know what you are asking, but if you want to see the ListView solution, create a new post asking for it

Comment: @rickkorsten Since your method is returning a String[] do this:

Comment: @rickkorsten 'String[] array_outside_method = getpathsFromJSON(JSONString);'